# Authenticating with Active Directory with Smart Card or Biometric Device

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-active-directory, smartcard, biometrics

I'm working on software that runs on a shared computer in a meeting room. The computer is logged into the network with a room account.

Is there a way without requiring the user to log out of the room account, to authenticate themselves using a Smart Card or Biometric Device against Active Directory? The user needs access to network shares and possibly other Active Directory secured resources.

This video from Ignite 2018 on the Surface Hub 2 has an example of what I'm trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPEE-zOcnKI. At 1:09 in the video, a second user is able to authenticate herself while the first user is still logged in.

Comment: The network of the meeting room and your work is same one or different?

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the video, this is new features for the Microsoft Surface Hub 2.

For the computer, for now, you could not log in and authenticate the user, especially using a Smart Card or Biometric Device against Active Directory. In the same network, you could use the remote desktop connection to connect your work computer, but this way cannot be authenticated with a smart card or Biometric Device.

Maybe this feature will be considered for the computer in the future.

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!